# How to maintain a call to python-twitter across multiple instances of a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple python twitter bot I am writing. 
I have a `TwitterInterface()` class as such:

```
class TwitterInterface():
def __init__(self):
    self.api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=APIKEY, consumer_secret=APISECRET,
              access_token_key=TOKENKEY,
              access_token_secret=TOKENSECRET)


def get_status(self, twitter_source, since=None):
     foo = self.api.blablabla()
```

I have a second class `Bot()` that handles various things such as storing twitter IDs from and sending calculated strings back to `TwitterInterface()`.

I would like to be able to create many instances of `Bot()` while maintaining one instance of `TwitterInterface()`. What is the proper method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to implement a [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Some would argue the 'best' way to do so is to not have a singleton at all, because singletons are bad for various reasons. In that case, you have to manually manage ensuring that each `Bot` is passed the correct `TwitterInterface`, perhaps though a `Bot` [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Alternatively, you can do the following to get the effect of a singleton in Python:

```
class TwitterInterface():
      _the_interface = None

      def __init__(...): # This should be called once and only once
          if TwitterInterface._thie_interface:
             raise Exception('There can be only one!')
          ...
          TwitterInterface._the_interface = self


 ...

     @classmethod
     def get_interface(cls):
         if cls._the_interface:
            return  cls._the_interface
         else:
            raise Exception('There is not yet one!')
```

All `Bot`s can now get the same copy of `TwitterInterface` by calling `TwitterInterface.get_interface()`, once the initial `TwitterInterface` has been built.

**Update:**

Note that a huge limitation of the singleton pattern is that, in this situation, it means that there can only ever be one user active in your application at a time. For example that code as written would make it impossible to have two `TwitterInterface` instances with separate API keys, if that is a valid thing to do (I'm not familiar with the `twitter.API` object at all). If that's a thing you might want to do, a [Multiton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) (aka a Registry) would probably be more useful. To accomplish that (without using a `MetaClass`)

```
class TwitterInterface():
      _the_interface = dict()

      def __init__(name, ...): # This should be called once and only once for each name
          if TwitterInterface._thie_interface.has_key(name):
             raise Exception('There can be only one!')
          ...
          TwitterInterface._the_interface[name] = self


 ...

     @classmethod
     def get_interface(cls, name):  # This now raises a KeyError if name isn't in the registry
         return  cls._the_interface[name]
```

Comment: This makes sense..thanks for posting links to design patterns, also very helpful. If the singleton is not the 'best' way, what other options are there to avoid multiple concurrent connections to the Twitter API?

Comment: The afore-mentioned bot factory would likely be the `best` way (I.E. you make another class, `BotFactory`, that takes a `TwitterInterface` as its constructor, and then has a method (say, `produce_bot()` which produces `Bot`s and assigns them its given API. Although you'll have to be more specific by what you mean by **concurrent** connections, as in a single-threaded application there will never be concurrent connections in the sense of two methods using the same API key making calls at the same time.

Comment: Note that a huge limitation of the singleton pattern is that, in this situation, it means that there can only ever be one user active in your application at a time. For example that code as written would make it impossible to have two `TwitterInterface` instances with separate API keys, if that is a valid thing to do (I'm not familiar with the `twitter.API` object at all). If that's a thing you might want to do, a [Multiton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) (aka a Registry) would probably be more useful.